# Executing PHP WeService script by clicking a link within an e-mail

Tags: encryption, php, web-service, rest

I'm receiving e-mail from my PHP/MySQL application with certain links.
I was thinking on including an UUID as part of the link, which would point to a Web Service that ONLY reads those UUIDs.
Those UUIDs will be stored in the database and the Web Service server will understand what to do for each UUID (execute a SQL statement linked to that UUID).
Once that UUID is received and script executed, the UUID will be marked as inactive to avoid anyone executing the same query

This may mean that the Web Service Client doesn't request User credentials to authenticate (to user doing the actual click on the link). 
Is this too insecure? Is it prone to sql injection or easy hacking? Should I use additional encryption schemes
Note that my Application is not SSL enabled

If feasible, What components/frameworks would you recommend? I, mean, would it be SOAP, WSDL, REST, etc.? Are there alternatives to Web Services for this?

Answer (score 1):

Flagging the UUID as inactive after the initial access would only be effective as long as you are the first user accessing the link. If anyone else manages to hijack your email message and access the link before you no amount of extra encryption around your web service will help.

You could encrypt the email sent to you (in S/MIME format, PGP or GPG for example). This would increase the likelihood that you will be the first one to access the links, but if someone is eavesdropping your connection (or the connection to your server) they will still be able to see the result of your link access.

As long as your web service only uses the UUID provided from the outside and looks up the actual SQL to execute from the database then I don't see the web service itself as any security issue, but it will depend on sufficiently random nonces/UUIDs so an attacker cannot predict them easily.

Also, you might want to consider having a maximum time to keep generated nonces/UUIDs around, both to make sure your database isn't growing infinitely large but also to make sure that links that you never clicked will deactivate.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario imposes multiple possible issues. Whether it is prone to SQL Injection or hacking cannot be answered here as this is fully environment and code dependent.

Eavesdropping could occur on server side during generation of the links, through the mail channel or on your own machine.

When you restrict the links you send and you plan to click on them anyway than even if a hacker would obtain the link and use it before you use it (before the UUID has expired) then all the hacker can do is to execute the query you have stored in a database. So there might be no attack vector here (except UUID guessing as @wj. has pointed out)

If the links lead you to some administration area then you are screwed as you provide no authentication and try to achieve security by obscurity (by keeping the links secret).

One way of reducing risk (in a probable bad way) is securing the transmitting channel by encrypting the mail with a asymmetric encryption, like PGP etc, this is described by @wj. Eavesdropping this and you lost again as you did not protect the resource (the server) but only the message leading to the server.

What I regard a better way is to put authentication around the server in terms of log-in credentials or some other sort of authentication.

Does the resource need to be protected? Why is it not already protected?

What framework you should use depends on your environment, is it PHP? Perl? ASP?
I would suggest to use the existing MVC Frameworks for given languages that includes the concept of authentication (Symfony, Zend, ASP MVC, etc).
However be aware that all those frameworks are not trivial and require some understanding as simply using a framework may expose more information about your server and hence possibly increase the attack vectors.

Of course there might be totally simple and build-in tools suitable for your need too, like using apache's htaccess mechanism to provide some simple but effective protection of webresources.
This could protect the link being called without proper credentials but does not necessarily protect your server as you might have a weak root password, a weak database admin password, etc.

The ways of getting compromised are so enormous. Even if you protect your resource well, having a CMS, a web-mailer or any other system installed on the same machine can provide an attack vector even if you have secured your link well (you might end with having a secure front-door but leave all the windows open, speaking in analogies :))